# How does DIBAL-H react with acid anhydrides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

I know DIBAL-H reduces carboxylic acids and some derivatives, but couldn’t find out about its reaction with acid anhydrides. Do these react? And what are the by-products (if any)?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Questions are the central focus of this site, but we ask that questions demonstrate an attempt to solve/understand the question to maintain quality.  Please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any references for this but my instinct is that Dibal-H will react with anhydrides, probably to give aldehydes

Comment: @Waylander ... yes, that’s what I thought, too, but I couldn’t find a reliable source to verify